# Real-time output from engines in IPython parallel?

Tags: ipython, ipython-parallel

I am running a bunch of long-running tasks with IPython's great [parallelization](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/) functionality.

How can I get real-time output from the ipengines' stdout in my IPython client?

E.g., I'm running `dview.map_async(fun, lots_of_args)` and `fun` prints to stdout. I would like to see the outputs as they are happening.

I know about `AsyncResult.display_output()`, but it's only available *after* all tasks have finished.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see stdout in the meantime by accessing `AsyncResult.stdout`, which will return a list of strings, which are the stdout from each engine.

The simplest case being:

```
print ar.stdout
```

You can wrap this in a simple function that prints stdout while you wait for the AsyncResult to complete:

```
import sys
import time
from IPython.display import clear_output

def wait_watching_stdout(ar, dt=1, truncate=1000):
    while not ar.ready():
        stdouts = ar.stdout
        if not any(stdouts):
            continue
        # clear_output doesn't do much in terminal environments
        clear_output()
        print '-' * 30
        print "%.3fs elapsed" % ar.elapsed
        print ""
        for eid, stdout in zip(ar._targets, ar.stdout):
            if stdout:
                print "[ stdout %2i ]\n%s" % (eid, stdout[-truncate:])
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(dt)
```

An [example notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/6171348) illustrating this function.

Now, if you are using older IPython, you may see an artificial restriction on access of the stdout attribute ('Result not ready' errors).
The information is available in the metadata, so you can still get at it while the task is not done:

```
rc.spin()
stdout = [ rc.metadata[msg_id]['stdout'] for msg_id in ar.msg_ids ]
```

Which is essentially the same thing that the `ar.stdout` attribute access does.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I really appreciate your work on IPython parallel and the effort you put in this answer. Great work!

Comment: The notebook should be probably updated though, becouse `any(stdouts)` raises an exception. :-/

Comment: Where are the attributes `ar._targets` and `ar.stdout` described?

Answer (score 0):

just in case somebody is still struggling with 
getting ordinary print-outputs of the individual kernels:

I adapted minrk's answer such that i get the output of each 
kernel as if it would have been a local one by constantly checking if the stdout of each kernel changes while the program is running.

```
asdf = dview.map_async(function, arguments)

# initialize a stdout0 array for comparison
stdout0 = asdf.stdout

while not asdf.ready():
    # check if stdout changed for any kernel
    if asdf.stdout != stdout0:
        for i in range(0,len(asdf.stdout)):
            if asdf.stdout[i] != stdout0[i]:
                # print only new stdout's without previous message and remove '\n' at the end
                print('kernel ' + str(i) + ': ' + asdf.stdout[i][len(stdout0[i]):-1])

                # set stdout0 to last output for new comparison
                stdout0 =  asdf.stdout
    else:
        continue


asdf.get()
```

outputs will then be something like:

```
kernel0: message 1 from kernel 0
kernel1: message 1 from kernel 1
kernel0: message 2 from kernel 0
kernel0: message 3 from kernel 0
kernel1: message 2 from kernel 0
...
```