# Again Real-time output from engines in IPython parallel?

Tags: ipython-parallel

I have the same question as in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086299/real-time-output-from-engines-in-ipython-parallel/18095126#18095126?newreg=7bdc800242c3492dbd4fdc26096a131c) and my ipython (0.13.1) does seem to have the 'Result not ready' error, so that I used the following change :

```
def wait_watching_stdout(ar, rc, dt=1, truncate=1000):
  while not ar.ready():
    rc.spin()
    stdouts = [ rc.metadata[msg_id]['stdout'] for msg_id in ar.msg_ids ]
    if not any(stdouts):
        continue
    # clear_output doesn't do much in terminal environments
    clear_output()
    print '-' * 30
    print "%.3fs elapsed" % ar.elapsed
    print ""
    for eid, stdout in zip(ar._targets, stdouts):
        if stdout:
            print "[ stdout %2i ]\n%s" % (eid, stdout[-truncate:])
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(dt)
```

The problem is that rc.spin seems to do something bad to my engines : they start working like crazy, hang, and then I need to kill the ipcluster command to stop them, as stopping the script is not enough.... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

operator error it seems..... The code above seems to do be doing what it is meant to do, though it was not exactly what I was expecting in my concrete use. Sorry for the erroneous post