# How to debug and fix iPython parallel's "Kernel Restarting" message on ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, ipython-parallel

Every time I run very time consuming task with `iPython parallel (ipyparallel)`, I receive a popup message "Kernel Restarting The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

[image]

What is a good way for debugging this situation? I print ever lines on my program, and probably right after finishing all process finish the kernel die and restarting.

i.e., in the following code, after executing `run_parallel` for several times (usually 10 times), the kernel dies before printing "finish parallel" message. Then, before dying, "finish run 99" has been printed every time.

Therefore, I guess the kernel dies when returning from parallel engines after finishing all parallel process. But I can not how to debug and fix it.

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
from IPython import parallel
from IPython.parallel import require

def run(x):
    # run process once for x
    ...
    print "finish run %d" % x
    return result

def run_parallel(num):
    print("run_parallel: %d times" % num)
    rc = parallel.Client()
    dview = rc[:]
    try:
        res = dview.map_async(run, range(100))
        wait_watching_stdout() # Real-time output from engines in IPython parallel (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086299/real-time-output-from-engines-in-ipython-parallel)
        print ("finish parallel")
        result = res.get()
    finally:
        rc.close()
    return result

all_result = []
for num in range(500):
    r = run_parallel(num)
    all_result.append(r)
```

#### My Environment

- Ubuntu 14.04
- python 2.7.10 on anaconda 2.4.0
- iPython 4.0.0
- ipyparallel 5.0.1